printf does not call my version of malloc
I overwritten malloc to use a static buffer with TLSF allocation. but then when I call printf, the regular malloc is called instead of my custom malloc.
void *malloc(size_t size) __attribute__((weak));
void *malloc(size_t size) {
    return tlsf_malloc(size);
}

how do I fix this?
EDIT: environment: FreeRTOS
compilation:
arm-none-eabi-g++ "filename.cpp" -mcpu=cortex-m7 -std=gnu++14 -g3 -DSTM32H753xx -DSTM32H753xx_Pragma_War -c
-O0 -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti -fno-use-cxa-atexit -Wall -fstack-usage -fcyclomatic-complexity
-MMD -MP -MF"Shared/ctl_timr.d" -MT"Shared/ctl_timr.o"  -mfpu=fpv5-d16 -mfloat-abi=hard -mthumb -o "Shared/ctl_timr.o"
I got the same issue without attribute((weak))

Describe your environment: OS, compiler, C library, link options...

It is tricky to replace the allocation system. You must redefine at least malloc, calloc, realloc, free, strdup, strndup and possibly some other functions.  Static linking is also a better option.

What is the rationale to adorn your malloc definition with __attribute__((weak))?

More importantly: where exactly is this code located and how does the standard lib get access to it? Because the standard lib won't execute user-defined functions sitting in your application tier no matter what you do there - you need to modify the standard lib.

Regarding the edit: So this isn't actually C but C++. It is going to be tremendously helpful for you to actually know which programming language you are coding in... Because to begin with, C and C++ use very different rules for name mangling and function overloading.

correct. what I have is something like: void* operator new(size_t size) {
return malloc(size);
}
void operator delete(void* ptr) noexcept {
free(ptr);
}
extern "C" {
void* malloc(size_t size) {
return tlsf_malloc(size);
}
void free(void* ptr) {
tlsf_free(ptr);
}
void* realloc(void* ptr, size_t size) {
return tlsf_realloc(ptr, size);
}
void* calloc(size_t nmemb, size_t size) {
return tlsf_calloc(nmemb, size);
}
}

@CatalinDemergian don't put tonsof code into comments, it's unreadable as you can see. Instead [edit] the question and put your code into the question.

In addition to needing to replace free as well, you need to ensure that you only link to object libraries for your library functions. If you link to dynamic library to provie fprintf () it will already be linked to some other malloc.


void *malloc(size_t size) __attribute__((weak));


Your version of malloc is not weak. Remove this line.

Still wouldn't make the standard lib call the custom malloc. At best they get a linker error regarding multiple definitions.

@Lundin: With a classical linker, this does work. It's only when you get into shared libraries that this stops working.

@Joshua I really don't see how. Especially since the OP isn't actually coding in C, as it turns out, but in C++ and its preference for name mangling.

You are supposed to be able to replace malloc(); the complete solution would look like this:
extern "C" {
void *malloc(size_t size) {
    return tlsf_malloc(size);
}
void *realloc(void *ptr, size_t size) {
    return tlsf_realloc(ptr, size);
}
void free(void *ptr) {
    tlsf_free(ptr, size);
}
void *calloc(size_t size, size_t n) {
    /* Error checking omitted for brevity */
    char *ptr = (char*)malloc(size * n);
    memset(ptr, 0, size * n);
    return ptr;
}
}

You have to provide all of these or it doesn't work. (You hope you get a link error.) Furthermore, some platforms require you to link statically or it still doesn't work.
This reason this works is when the linker resolves symbols it takes symbols in the .o files before any symbols in the .a files; discarding .o files inside the .a files that have their symbols already defined. (In the old days you had to topsort your libraries and library inclusion order however those days are long gone.)
If this yields a duplicate symbol error on link, file a bug against the runtime library.
Your test case is dodgy; printf() normally doesn't call malloc(). Test with fopen() or strdup().

"printf() normally doesn't call malloc()": Glibc's does or at least did, see https://github.com/bminor/glibc/commit/6caddd34bd7ffb5ac4f36c8e036eee100c2cc535.

@user17732522: Fun rare case requiring a very large string format directive.
